# D-Link L2 & L3 Network Setup

Tags: routing, subnet, layer2, layer3

I'm currently setting up my new network using D-Link DGS-1510 series gigabit stackable smart managed switches. It is the first time i use this L2 & L3 switches and I'm trying to setup the following scenario:

```
    Internet
       |
       |
    firewall
       | (internal IP: 192.168.1.254)
       |
       |
+-------------+
| L3 - switch |
+-------------+
   |       |
   |       |
   |       | (subnet: 192.168.5.0/24)
   |   +-----------+
   |   | L2-switch |
   |   +-----------+
   |      |  |  |  |  (connections to client computers)
   |
   |
   | (subnet: 192.168.9.0/24)
+-----------+ 
| L2-switch |
+-----------+
  |  |  |  |  (connections to servers)
```

The L2 & L3 switches are all DGS-1510 series devices. Each computer located in the two subnets, should be able to access the internet. Also should it be possible that the clients can access the servers, and the servers should be allowed to access the clients. Also the servers should be able to talk to other servers in the same network and the client should be able to access all other clients in the same network.

Therefore I created 2 VLANs on the L3 switch. The first one for the 192.168.9.0 network. I gave the port, where the L2 switch was connected, the IP Address 192.168.9.254. On the L2-Switch I added this IP Address as Gateway. For the other network i created the same configuration except that the 9 was replaced by the 9.

Additionally I added the IP 192.168.1.254 (firewall) as gateway to the L3 switch.

This was enough, that the each computer from each network was able to access the internet. But I was not able to send a ping from network 9 to network 5 and vice versa.

This is my first VLAN and routing configuration and I cannot find suitable tutorials for my problems. Is there someone who can help me with my configuration or does know some good tutorials.

Thank you
Andi

Comment: Andi, from your information, it sounds like you've done this correctly.  Are these Windows computers?   Is there a chance that Windows firewall is blocking pings?

Comment: Maybe Windows blocks the pings. - Good idea. Dell offers 3 types of VLAN Prots: Hybrid, Trunk and Access. Currently I use Access. Which one should I use? Thank you.

Comment: All your ports should be access.

Comment: currently I'm connected to network 192.168.5.0/24 over the corresponding L2-switch. I'm able to access the L2-Switch for the Network 192.168.9.0/24 using the IP address 192.168.9.1, but I'm not able to ping any other device of the Network 192.168.9.0/24. The devices I'm trying to ping don't use a firewall. Below you can find my current routing table <pre>
IP-Adresse Maske Gateway Schnittstellenname Kosten Protokoll
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.254 vlan1 1/1 S*
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Direkt verbunden vlan1 C
192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0 Direkt verbunden vlan5 C
192.168.9.0 255.255.255.0 Direkt ver

Comment: Please post the routing tables from one workstation and one server, and the route table on the L3 switch.

Comment: I just deployed DGS-1510-28 in collocation with IPv4 and IPv6. It's a new product and information from D-Link is scarce but they do try. Have you resolved your issue yet?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to do to make this work, is to create the switch virtual interfaces (SVIs) on the L3 switch and assign them IP addresses for both VLAN 1 and VLAN 2. Then you need to setup your end devices with the default gateway address, which would be the IP address of the SVI in the approperiate VLAN and turn on routing on the L3 switch.

You do not need to configure default gateways on the L2 switches. You would have to do this, if you would like to have L2 switch as a default gateway for your end devices...
Then the scenario would be to make an SVI on the L2 switch and point the default-gateway to the L3 switch which would make the routing.

Also... The ports connected to the switches can be normal access ports, unless you want to have 2 different VLANs on the same L2 switch.

I hope that I helped.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I gave the port, where the L2 switch was connected, the IP Address
>   192.168.9.254. On the L2-Switch I added this IP Address as Gateway.

The L2 switch needs gateway only for mgmt afaik.

The L3 switch should have 2 logical VLAN interfaces, and both should be up. These VLAN interfaces then should be the default gateways for your clients.

All VLANs on an L3 switch, by default, communicate back and forth. The ports on which both the L2 switches connect to the L3, and vice versa, should be trunks.

Issue the equivalent of the `ip routing` command on the L3 switch.

[Cisco's inter-vlan routing guide.](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html#steps)

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but note that the DGS1510 switch cannot use its own IP addresses for routing.  I want to create something very similar to Andi's setup, and logged a support case with DLink when I couldn't get it to work.  The reply was that the DGS1510 cannot route to its own IP addresses.

Comment: "Cannot use its own IP address for routing" is ambiguous - a router requires an IP address to be used by others. However, "cannot route to its own IP address" is rather obvious - if the router uses itself as gateway for a route that would (usually) create a routing loop.