# Making vlans talking to other vlans

Tags: vlan

Hi im trying to make vlans talk to eachother, i have 2 3560 switches, i put addresses on the vlans just not sure why its protocol is down cuz i think its supposed to be up/up, also how do i know its working?

```
Switch#sh ip interfa brie vlan 10
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan10                 192.168.11.254  YES manual up                    down
```

Comment: @erosales Your help is very welcome, but you should put questions here in comments.  That way other people can search easier for answers to this question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The VLAN interface protocol would be up if you would have a port that is up or if those VLANs were present on a trunk link.

3560 is a Layer 3 switch so to route between vlans or you need to do is to type 'ip routing' command and assign proper gateways on the end devices.

Take a look at [D-Link L2 & L3 Network Setup](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17673/d-link-l2-l3-network-setup/28880#28880)

That was a similar quesiton to yours.

Regards

Comment: "_3560 is a Layer 3 switch..._" That depends on the license level installed on the switch.

Comment: Oh really? Good to know. Thanks! Does it goes the same for 3750?

Comment: Yes. Any of the 2K, 3K, or 4K switches can be ordered with just LanBase. IP routing requires at least IPBase, and more advanced routing features require other license levels.

Comment: Cisco 3560 are layer 3 switches no matter license.  I bet the guy was missing 'ip routing'.

Answer (score 2):

The interface could be down because you have no ports on that VLAN that are up.

Or, you have already configured another VLAN interface on that switch.  On  layer 2 switches, you can only have one VLAN interface up at the same time.

If you want the two VLANs to talk to each other, you will need a router, or a layer 3 swith.

Answer (score 0):

Native vlan mismmatch? 
Are both sides set to trunking?
what are the allowed vlans on the link?
encapsulation set?

Just a few things that came to mind...Also ip routing could cause the issue depending on what your network environment setup is....

Cheers,